# SQL not invoked when SELECTing Entity with JPQL

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, eclipselink, jpql

I have a table FAQ ( Frequently asked questions )

Here's the Bean:

```
   package projet.helpdesk.beans;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="faq")
public class FAQ {

    @Id
    private int id_qr;
    private int id_technicien;
    private String question;
    private String reponse;

    public int getId_qr() {
        return id_qr;
    }
    public void setId_qr(int id_qr) {
        this.id_qr = id_qr;
    }
    public int getId_technicien() {
        return id_technicien;
    }
    public void setId_technicien(int id_technicien) {
        this.id_technicien = id_technicien;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getReponse() {
        return reponse;
    }
    public void setReponse(String reponse) {
        this.reponse = reponse;
    }

}
```

This is the DAO class:
The function `public List<FAQ> chargerFAQ()` is supposed to return a list of FAQ.
The JPQL query is: `private static final String JPQL_SELECT_ALL = "SELECT f FROM FAQ f";`

```
`package projet.helpdesk.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import projet.helpdesk.beans.FAQ;

@Stateless
public class FAQDao {

    private static final String JPQL_SELECT_ALL = "SELECT f FROM FAQ f";

    private static final String JPQL_SELECT_QR = "SELECT f FROM FAQ f WHERE id_qr=:id_qr";
    private static final String PARAMETER = "id_qr";

    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "bdd_helpdesk_PU" )
    private EntityManager       em;


    public void creer( FAQ faq ) throws IllegalArgumentException, DAOException {
        try {
            em.persist(faq);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            throw new DAOException( e );
        }     
    }

    public List<FAQ> chargerFAQ() throws DAOException {
        List<FAQ> listefaq;
        Query query = em.createQuery(JPQL_SELECT_ALL);
        try {
            listefaq = (List<FAQ>) query.getResultList();
        } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
            return null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
        return listefaq;
    }

    public FAQ trouverQR(int id_qr) throws DAOException{
        FAQ qr;
        Query query = em.createQuery(JPQL_SELECT_QR);
        query.setParameter(PARAMETER, id_qr);
         try {
                qr = (FAQ) query.getSingleResult();
            } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
                return null;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new DAOException(e);
            }
            return qr;
    }

}
`
```

Persisting the FAQ entity was successful, but loading the data does'nt return anything, maybe the query instruction is wrong?

Here's the servlet:

```
`@WebServlet ( urlPatterns = { "/afficherfaq" })
public class AfficherFaq extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private FAQDao faqDao;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ChargerFaq.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<FAQ> lfaq = faqDao.chargerFAQ();
        request.setAttribute("lfaq", lfaq);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ChargerFaq.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }   
}
```

`
And the Entity's path is included in the persistence.xml file.

**EDIT:** Added  JSP code.
JSP file to show the result:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.css" />
<title>Foire aux questions</title>
</head>
<body>
Test
    <c:forEach items="${lfaq}" var="faq" varStatus="boucle">
    <fieldset>
    <p><span class="info">Question:</span></p><br>
        <p>${faq.question}</p><br>
    <p><span class="info">Reponse:</span></p><br>
        <p>${faq.reponse}</p><br>
    </fieldset><br><br>
    </c:forEach>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Persisting the FAQ entity was successful" - it didn't get an exception, but it didn't do anything either.  Changes (persist, merge, delete etc) are only synchronized with the database when there is a flush call or the transaction commits, so nothing happened.  And changes are usually only visible once the transaction commits.  Wrap your method in a transaction.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm doing my best to understand your comment, actually similar code to the one i posted worked out, and there i added the jsp code, can't understand what you mean by transaction ..

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html where it describes how JPA uses transactions and how they are fundamental to database operations.  If your operation is not participating in a transaction, JPA will not ever write out anything to the database.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, it still worked for me without using transaction, maybe it is added by default through eclipseLink?

Comment: No, EclipseLink/JPA doesn't handle transactions for you.  IF it is working elsewhere, you must be using JTA and having the container wrap things in a transaction.  When in doubt, call em.flush and JPA will throw an exception if it isn't within a transaction.

Comment: Today i learned something.